# HTML5 Boot strap, spring JSTL Page is not displaying as I want it to

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, jstl, jsp-tags

I am very new to HTML Bootstrap etc. what I am trying to do is, I am making a side menu bar having menus as the month of the particular year, and its drop-down should have the events name occurred those months. and whenever the user clicks on any events, Information about that event should be displayed at the center of the page, this information is in the form of youtube videos which I am displaying in an iframe.
But what I am getting is, doesn't matter if the user clicks or don't click on any event, the page displays all the videos one after another.

I am using spring data as backend and jsp for the view, using JSTL c:foreach tag

the code is as follows.

```
 <div class="row">
        <!-- Sidebar Column -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group">
                <c:forEach items="${show.months}" var="month">
                    <a  class="list-group-item">${month.name}</a>
                    <c:forEach items="${month.events}" var="event">
                         <a  class="list-group-item">${event.event_name}</a>

                    </c:forEach>

             </c:forEach>
```

and the code to display the iframe is like this

```
     <div class="col-md-9">
         <c:forEach items="${show.months}" var="month">
             <h2>${month.name}</h2>

              <c:forEach items="${month.events}" var="event">

                    ${event.event_link}


             </c:forEach>       
        </c:forEach>
                 <br><br>
    </div>
```

I know this is very laymen kind of code, But I am really stuck here, can you please help me?

Comment: it's showing all the videos because that's how you've coded it. You need to make use of Ajax if you want to be able to fetch all the events for a specific month when a user clicks on it. Here's how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, will check